# Improving the readability of automated text generation based on a database query

Tags: r, string, text, replace, gsub

I am trying to improve the readability of automated text generation based on a database query.

is there a neat way to perform these substitutions ? To do the following in 1 command instead of 6?

```
x<-c("Te( )st", "Test()", "Test ()", "Test ( )", "Test ,,", "Test,, ", "Test , ")
out<-c("Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test,", "Test, ", "Test,") 

x<-gsub(pattern = "( ", replacement = "(", x, fixed = T)
x<-gsub(pattern = " )", replacement = ")", x, fixed = T)
x<-gsub(pattern = " ,", replacement = ",", x, fixed = T)
x<-gsub(pattern = "()", replacement = "", x, fixed = T)
x<-gsub(pattern = ",,", replacement = ",", x, fixed = T)
x<-gsub(pattern = " ,", replacement = ",", x, fixed = T)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```r
x<-c("Te( )st", "Test()", "Test ()", "Test ( )", "Test ,,", "Test,, ", "Test , ")
gsub("\\(\\s*\\)|\\s+(?=[,)])|(?<=\\()\\s+|(,),+", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
# => [1] "Test"   "Test"   "Test "  "Test "  "Test,"  "Test, " "Test, "
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/39xzrW) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qEIzjo/1). *Details*:

- `\(\s*\)|` - `(`, zero or more whitespaces and then a `)`, or
- `\s+(?=[,)])|` - one or more whitespaces and then either `,` or `)`, or
- `(?<=\()\s+|` - one or more whitespaces immediately preceded with a `(` char, or
- `(,),+` - a comma captured into Group 1 and then one or more commas.

The replacement is the Group 1 value, namely, if Group 1 matched, the replacement is a single comma, else, it is an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mgsub::mgsub`.

```r
a = c("( ", " )", " ,", "()",",,") #pattern
b = c("(", ")", ",", "",",")       #replacement
x<-c("Te( )st", "Test()", "Test ()", "Test ( )", "Test ,,", "Test,, ", "Test , ")

mgsub::mgsub(x, a, b, fixed = T)
#[1] "Te()st"  "Test"    "Test "   "Test ()" "Test,,"  "Test, "  "Test, "
```

You might want to add other patterns to get the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multigsub` function which is a wrapper of `gsub` function in R. You can find the documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/qdap/versions/2.4.3/topics/multigsub).

Here's the code:

```
multigsub(c("(", ")", ",", "()", ",,", " ,"), c("(", ")", ",", "", ",", ","), x, fixed = T)
```